# Creating a bottom bar/panel on Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a Google Chrome extension with a bar that appears along the bottom like the Chrome "Developer tools".  I dont want to use content scripts, if possible. Does chrome extension provide any way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a panel IN the developer tools using the [devtools API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/devtools.html) but it sounds like you want something separate from that.

The bad new is, unfortunately, there is no way to do this with out content scripts - Chrome is very strict on what it allows you to do. Why, may I ask, do you not want to use content scripts?

Comment: I am new to Chrome. What I basically want to so is create a toolbar similar to Firefox that is persitent across windows, tabs etc. My understanding is content scripts get displayed only before/ after dom load. Developer tools may not be the way to go either since they do not seem to be persistent. What would be the best way to achieve this ?

Comment: I just had a quick glance at the documentation, it appears content scripts can be injected before the DOM is rendered by setting the `run_at` property of `content_scripts` in the manifest.json to `document_start`. Have a look at the documentation here: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html good luck! :)